# How to use a global defined variable in scrapy-spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

How could I use a global defined variable (pandas data frame) `df` within a scrapy-spider?

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('home/test.csv')

class Spider:
  name = 'test'
  start_urls = 'https://test.org'

  def parse(self, response):
    data = response.css('get-data-here').extract()

    for i in data:
      final_output = **df**[(**df**[0]==re.search(r'[test]', i).group(1)), 1].item()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to declare variable inside class, if you want to
> initialize do that in constructor.

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
import re

class Spider:
  name = 'test'
  start_urls = 'https://test.org'
  
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
      self.df = pd.read_csv('home/test.csv')

  def parse(self, response):
    data = response.css('get-data-here').extract()

    ## use data frame with self.df
```